# NO matching function for call to 'std::queue<node>::push(NULL)'

Tags: oop, c++11

I am solving a problem and came across this obstacle .
Why this code gives me an error

```
queue<node>q;
node n;
q.push(n);
q.push(NULL);
```

'no matching function for call to 'std::queue::push(NULL)'

And when I do this change

```
queue<node*>q;
node* n = new node();
q.push(n);
q.push(NULL);
```

It works Fine!

Comment: Your queue contains `node`s, but you're trying to push `NULL` which is not one.

Comment: You could use `q.push({})` which might work both with `std::queue<node>` as well as `std::queue<node *>`. In the former case, it will push a default constructed `node`, in the second case it would push a default constructed *pointer* to a `node`, which will be the same as pushing `nulltpr` (don't use `NULL`, it's a C thing).

Comment: Your `node` is not initializable by NULL , you will get the same error for `node n = NULL;`